# All the trees from randomForest-model are use all the attributes of object, but not only mtry?

Tags: r, random-forest

I have trained model for classification task in R using randomForest - "RF_Model"

```
RF_Model <- randomForest(measure ~., data = dat), mtry=3, importance=TRUE,ntree=500)
print(RF_Model)
```

returns:

> Call:  randomForest(formula = measure ~ ., data = dat) 
>                  Type of random forest: classification
>                        Number of trees: 500 No. of variables tried at each split: 3

Each object, which uses in that model, has 15 attributes.
In my understanding (the basic knowledge I have got from [here](https://www.listendata.com/2014/11/random-forest-with-r.html)): mtry = number of random variables used in each tree.
So, I thought, that for each sample decision tree (from those 500 trees in the forest) will be used only 3 different attributes from 15.

But when I tried to check that - I found that all the 15 attributes are used for each tree in the forest:

```
k <- 209 #tried here distinct values from 1 to 500
tree <- getTree(RF_Model, k, labelVar = TRUE)
```

and as the result, tree returns the tree with 19-27 levels of depth, and always all the 15 attributes are used for the tree.
[image: one of the trees and distinct attributes which are used in it]

What I am doing wrong or misunderstood?
Why for the small trees in the forest (No. of variables tried at each split: 3) have been used not 3 distinct attributes, but always all 15?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each object, which uses in that model, has 15 attributes. In my understanding (the basic knowledge I have got from https://www.listendata.com/2014/11/random-forest-with-r.html): mtry = number of random variables used in each tree. So, I thought, that for each sample decision tree (from those 500 trees in the forest) will be used only 3 different attributes from 15.

This is incorrect. `mtry` is the number of variables tried at each **split.** A nice introduction to [random-forest](/questions/tagged/random-forest) can be found in *[Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/).*

Comment: For reference, the technique of ensembling models trained on random subsamples of attributes is called _Feature Bagging_ or _Attribute Bagging_ (+1 btw)

Comment: Related: [In Random Forest, why is a random subset of features chosen at the node level rather than at the tree level?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357990/1352)